# How To Create a SOAP Service using Spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-ws

Hi I just want to know whether Spring support SOAP based web services or not, if Spring support SOAP web services then please share the step wise tutorial so that i can start hands on with SOAP with Spring.

Comment: May [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/site/reference/html/tutorial.html) can help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Spring WS](http://projects.spring.io/spring-ws/) project is for you.

Here is a Guide: https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-web-service

And samples on the matter: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-ws-samples

Comment: I want Spring to generate WSDL for me , i dont want to explicitly go and type the XML, will it work like that

Comment: @UtsavVishnoi : It can generate a WSDL for you, but then you still need to type the XSD that is needed to generate it. You can use the `Request` and `Response` suffix to automatically map elements to operations. Check out [the tutorial](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/site/reference/html/tutorial.html#tutorial-service-contract) for more information.